# Contact Deletion through REST API - POST Error 400

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

Fetching an error code 400 for the below code:

```
<script runat="server"> 

Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

/* create the payload in JSON format */

var payload = '{"grant_type":"client_credentials",';
`enter code here`    payload += '"client_id":"id",';
        payload += '"client_secret":"secret",';
        payload += '"scope":null,';
        payload += '"account_id":"mid"}';
  var url = "https://customurl.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token";
  var contentType = 'application/json';

         /* perform HTTP Post request to get a new OAuth 2.0 access token */
         var accessTokenResult = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload);
         var tokenObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenResult["Response"][0]);
         var accessToken = tokenObj.access_token;

/* execute */
  try{
var url1 = 'https://customurlfrominstalledpackage.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/contacts/v2/contacts/actions/delete?type=listReference';
var headerNames1 = ["Authorization"];
var headerValues1 = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
var deKe = 'koreacompanyrecords';
var payload2 = '{"deleteOperationType": "ContactAndAttributes","targetList": {"listType": {"listTypeID": 3},"listKey": "Deletionrecords"},"deleteListWhenCompleted": false,"deleteListContentsWhenCompleted": false}'; 
    var contentType1 = 'application/json';
 
var endpoint = url1;
var result = HTTP.Post(endpoint, contentType1, payload2, headerNames1, headerValues1); 
   Write("OAuth 2.0 Access Token for you: " + accessToken);}
  catch(e){
    Write(Stringify(e));
  }
</script>
```

some say its an error with the endpoint. what can be the possible error. Please guide.

Comment: have you tested your call in postman? 400 typically means a bad json payload

Comment: Have you verified your Auth call is working and it is for sure your contactdelete call?